# How To Get Date From Database and Load it into Custom DataGridView Column in VB Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am a beginner with VB.NET WindowsForm, I am using Visual Studio 2010 and need help on Several issues on DateTimePicker on DGV, I already managed to create a DatetimePickerColumn (DTPColumn) on a databound DGV usinghttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx, My first question is how do I load the Dates from my  database to the DTPcolumn that was added in dgv without the DTPCell replacing the original date? Please and Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best way of doing it but atleast it works. After you've set the datasource you can do this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
      Dim gridComboBox As New CalendarCell
      DGV.Item(<Date column index>, i) = gridComboBox
Next
```

This rewrites the column you have the dates in to calendar cells. This will however throw errors if the column with the dates actually aren't dates.  is of course to be changed to the apropriate index. With this there is no need for a manually created column.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Im going to try this now. Do I have to remove the things I placed using msdn's tutorial? Also, I have another question, Please bear with me, I'm really sorry since I'm just really new with vb. All I want to be able to do to my DGV is to be able to input a date there using a datetimepicker (outside of DGV) and also save in my database(sql), is there a simpler way of doing that instead of having to create a new column with datetimepicker? Please and thank you.

Comment: I managed to add dates now without using datetimepickercolumn. I'll use this instead of creating a dtpcolumn Thanks for your help anyway.